# 'Method 'Range' of object failed' when setting range over certain columns

Tags: excel, vba

I know that theres a lot of questions already been asked but I have found an odd instance for this error. In my code I have the user select a group of columns then I use that selection to build a string (called 'bld') to set the range. When the user selects say columns `A:F` or `AA:AF` everything works as expected however when `U:AC` were selected this error popped up. If I write it in directly the code runs fine and I have checked that 'bld' is actually coming up as `$U4:$AC75` but it still won't work. Any thoughts on why this could be happening? Set `rng2 = ws2.Range(bld)` is where the error occurs.

```
Sub reformat()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet 
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, bld As String
Dim Ar As String, a As Range, b As Range, hrs As Double, man As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("by_hours")
Set rng = ws.Range("H2:H" & ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)
Set rng2 = Application.InputBox("Select Week range", , , , , , , 8)
bld = Left(rng2.Address, InStr(rng2.Address, ":") - 1) & "4" & _
           Right(rng2.Address, InStr(rng2.Address, ":")) & "75"
Set rng2 = ws2.Range(bld)
```

Comment: `Right` should be `Mid` (which is why it is generating `$U4$AC75` instead of the `$U4:$AC75` your questions states), but the answer by chris neilsen shows a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `bid`, when input range is into a two letter column returns a string missing the `:`.  Also if user selects a range of cells rather than entire column it will return unexpected results.

To fix, don't use string manipulation at all, but manipulate the selected range

```
Set rng2 = rng2.EntireColumn.Resize(72).Offset(3, 0)
```

Comment: Damn, rookie mistake. I printed the bld string once and missed the fact the ':' was missing. You are correct about the user selection as well, I hadn't thought of that because only I have been using it at this stage but If I had to delegate it would have become an issue. Top Answer!

Comment: Just as an FYI for anybody coming across this. As I was looping through rng2 like this `for each a in rng 2....` it was indexing the entire range instead looping through each cell so I had to add `Set rng2 = ws2.range(rng2.address)`

Comment: @J.Peel the better way is `For Each a In rng2.Cells`